# Erro de compilação nesta linha de codigo

Tags: c++

Estou com um algoritmo aqui que está apresentando erro de compilação nesta linha `#include "filadvet.hpp"`. Não vou mostrar o código todo porquê o algoritmo é grande e não há necessidade. O restante do código funciona, mas o erro de compilação aparece na linha que mencionei acima.

Segue o trecho do código:

```
#include <assert.h> /**< Necessário para uso da macro "assert" */
#include <cstdlib> /**< Necessário para uso do NULL */
#include "filadvet.hpp" // erro de compilção é aqui!

using namespace std;

struct FilaDVet {
    int itens[TAM_MAX]; /**< Vetor que armazena os elementos da fila. */            
    int inicio; /**< Variável que indica a posição do primeiro elemento da fila. */
    int fim; /**< Variável que indica a próxima posição vazia da fila. */
};

/* 
 * Retorna o próximo valor do índice i, de forma circular. 
 * Ou seja, se i == TAM_MAX - 1, retorn 0. Caso contrário, retorna i + 1.
 * A palavra-chave "static" na assinatura desta função garante que ela só estará disponível
 * para uso dentro deste arquivo.
 */
static int incrementar(int i) {
    return ((i + 1) % TAM_MAX);
}
```

Restante do algoritmo...

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione a mensagem de erro.

Comment: A informação da pergunta não é suficiente para que a fonte do erro seja determinada. Além disso, você está utilizou uma tag inadequada na pergunta (C#).